# Include system timer in use case diagram

Tags: design, requirements, user-story, user-experience, use-case

[image]

Here in my use case diagram, an sms will be sent to a referenced person by the applicant automatically by the system when an applicant fills up and submits a form. Here as the SMS sending is performed by the system, is it right to include system timer performing sms sending in the use case diagram shown below? If not, what should I replace it with.?

Answer (score 1):

> is it right to include system timer performing sms sending in the use
>   case diagram shown below? If not, what should I replace it with.?

Actors in use case diagrams don't have to be humans. It may as well be another system or the system itself.

I would replace the "system timer" box with an actor labelled "Alerting system" (or whatever your system is called).